# How to solve $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)}{x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I came up with this integral question myself. $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)}{x}dx$. I have no idea how to solve it. I tried Feynman with a couple different parameterizations and also IBP with $u=\ln(\sin x)\ln(\cos x)$ and $dv=\frac{1}{x}$. All of these methods I tried yielded some substantial problems. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The graph says about a semi elliptic integral, [see here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rx5krvkjr0)

Comment: $\approx 0.1807$. CAS doesn't seem friendly to it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I don't mean to stifle your creativity, but the vast majority of definite integrals don't admit a closed-form. But who knows, maybe this one does. Keep trying!